# Is it possible to type equations in DIY (similar to that in math.stackexchange)?

Tags: feature-request

It doesn't appear that the method that math.stackexchange.com uses for typing equations is available in the DIY stack.  Is there another markup that's being used instead?

Comment: I don't think it works anywhere but Math.SE. [Not even on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87826/244695)

Answer (score 1):

The math-typing feature (which is named MathJax, by the way) is enabled on a few SE sites, but not this one at the moment. Our standard procedure when we get any request for a special site plugin like this is to ask for two things:

- community support on meta
- evidence that it would make a significant improvement to post quality

In other words, edit the question to include examples of several posts that would benefit from the use of the equation formatter and get it upvoted, and we'll reevaluate.

The Math meta community has provided [a handy guide to MathJax features](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can lean on, or if that's too long and infodump-y, you could check out [the standard SE help center article about MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).